# When the halacha says we must set kevua ittim

Tags: halacha

When the halacha says that we must set kevua ittim for learning does it mean that if I study today at ten thirty and tomorrow at eleven thirty and so on I do not fulfill my obligation of set times for learning. I feel like life has so many turns and its not pashut to keep the same time, same beit midrash. Although I learnt for a good time in a beit midrash at set times. Now my Rebbe has passed away and its empty there and I have no chevruta. What should I do? I search around but I dont have the same circumstance to learn at a set time at a set place. it gets unmotivating to learn alone, what is some good practical advice for me and people who might be in the same category. Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel and welcome to MY! Glad to have you here. You might want to take a look at our [tour]. One thing that I might suggest is that this is a very poor forum for personal questions like this - you should probably find a Rebbe to ask this to. Bd”e on the passing of your previous one, and I wish you much hatzlacha on your journey.

Comment: This seems Too Broad to me.

Comment: Hi Daniel, if you wish to talk about finding a new makom Torah or chavrusah, I may have ideas for you. You can contact me via email if you wish at davidariel25@gmail.com, hatzlachah rabbah

Answer (score 1):

I can see where you may get confused. The term *kove'ah* has a nuance of "fixing" or "setting" implying that it has to be the same thing that never changes. But, I don't think in this context it means that you need to have the same time each day. It means "establishing a fixed amount of time." I.e., establish an hour, 15 minutes, etc. for learning. Ideally, it should be the same time slot, but, of course circumstances will arise that will change things. That doesn't mean all is lost. The idea is to establish a fixed interval, and, make the best effort to adhere to it.

There are numerous online resources available for learning, and there are various methods. It depends what you like to learn. This past week, for example, many communities in U.S. began a 5 minute WhatsApp group focusing on hilchot *lashon hara*. I haven't yet signed up, myself, as I am still trying to get the email address. Let me know if this would interest you.

See [Partners in Torah](https://www.partnersintorah.org/) or [Jnet.org](http://www.jnet.org/). They will match you with someone either in your area or you can learn via Skype or other similar method. Technology has really vastly improved the means to learn Torah with others - be it 1 person or a group. These days, with almost everyone having a computer, I see little reason why someone cannot find a way to learn with another.

Comment: A belated welcome, @mroll. Would you mind editing your comment into the answer?

Comment: I would like to related something which I learned from one of my Rebees, Harav Meir Stern Shlit"a, Rosh yeshivah of the Yeshivah Gedolah of Passaic (NJ). Before each Bain Hazmanim he would express the importance of learning a minimum amount of time every single day during Bain Hazmanim. He would say as follows "Each bochur should decide for himself how much time he can take upon himself to learn every day. This learning schedule should not be missed for any reason whatsoever short of pikuach nefesh." (continued in following comment).

Comment: (continued from previous comment) - He would then advise us as follows: Each Bochur should decide on an amount of daily learning time which he feels he will absolutely not miss whatsoever. After he makes that decision, he should DIVIDE THE AMOUNT IN HALF! and take upon himself half of that."

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore The last bit of advice and the overall strategy is about the smartest idea that I've heard in a while. I assume that this is for adult kollel? This type of advice probably would not work that well with younger kids. They really need a "set shiur" to attend.

Comment: Chazak V'Ematz! May your efforts to succed in Hasmodas Hatorah bring you Seyayta Dishmaya to be able to find the time and true cheshek to be mekayem "u'vahem nehegeh yomam volayla.